# Super long "Loading render kernels" using macbook pro 2018 GPU rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm using a macbook pro (mid 2018) with Radeon pro 560X, to render on GPU. Whenever I hit render on GPU, the "loading render kernels" takes ages. And I never manage to render on GPU.
What can I do? The same problem with both Blender 2.79b and 2.8.

Cheers,
Gaofeng

Answer (score 2):

I also use macbook pro 2018.

I recognized that we have two opencl GPU (Intel and Radeon)

If we check both and Start rendering, Blender is stop and CVMCompiler process will have crazy amount of memory.

If we turn off the intel (use only Radeon), It works well.

I think Blender supports only Radeon not Intel.

But Radeon gpu rendering is slower than just CPU rendering.

[image]

[How to make cycle rendering faster](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles)

Thank you.

Comment: A spot-on answer!